# Use @Html.ValidationMessageFor or other validation (custom messages) on pure html elements in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, validation

Because I use a plugin called select2, I need to define the select lists in my application in pure Html (so without any helpers) like so:

```
<select name="TopicIds" id="topDrop" multiple style="width: 700px" required>
            @foreach (var top in ((List<Topic>)ViewBag.TopIds).Where(top => top.MainTopic == null))
            {
                <option value="@top.TopicId" class="optionGroup">@top.Name</option>
                foreach (var subTopic in top.SubTopics)
                {
                    <option value="@subTopic.TopicId" class="optionChild">@subTopic.Name</option>
                }
            }
        </select>
```

As you can see 1 element needs to be chosen, that's why I set the "required" attribute.

The validation happens, when the form submits it doesn't go through when nothing is selected in the list. I would like to set a custom error message though when the validation for the field happens.

Normally you would use the helper `@html.ValidationMessageFor()`, but that doesn't seem to be working with this pure html control. You can see the select list is binded to the property "TopicIds" in my ViewModel.

I tried this: `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TopicIds)`, the only message I get is the default "This field is required", strangely enough only when this helper is defined...

How can I customize this message? I've been seraching for a while and tried all kinds of solutions with JavaScript and such, but nothing seems to change the message, I always get "This field is required.".

Anyone know how to do this? I'm using all this in an ASP.NET MVC 4 web application.

Comment: is this github repository http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/ the select2 plugin you refer to

Comment: Yep that's the one ;)

Answer (score 0):

Annotate the property in your ViewModel

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "My Custom Message")]
public string Id {get;set;}
```

Then you `Html.ValidationMessageFor`

Comment: I tried this, but it is not working. If I don't specify the required attribute for the `<select>` no validation happens at all. When I do specifiy the required attribute, I get the standard "This field is required attribute." which I can't seem to be able to change ...

Comment: I suspect the required message you are seeing is one generated by the browser. If you removed the required attribute from the HTML element and do the standard ModelState.IsValid check in the server POST action the you would almost certainly see the correct message following postback when the view re-renders. To use client side unobtrusive validation you will need to write methods allowing you to add the correct data-* attributes to the element manually.